# Can "one" be substituted for qualifier + noun

Tags: grammar

Is it a correct sentence in English:

> The opening bracket count does not match the closing one.

which is supposed to be a shortened form of:

> The opening bracket count does not match the closing bracket count.

In other words is it OK to replace "bracket count" by "one" in this case?

Comment: Please do not edit your answer to invalidate an existing answer without providing a note about it. I initially downvoted the answer here because it didn't match your question. Only then did I realize it had answered the original form of your question, and I changed my vote in time.

Comment: I had edited your question to provide such a note, but then removed it after the existing answer was modified so it was appropriate to the new version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be "The opening bracket count does not match the closing bracket count." Using "the closing one" does not work because there is a count of opening or closing brackets, not an opening or closing count of brackets. Using "the closing bracket one" would be correct, but is only two letters shorter.

Comment: "The open and close bracket counts do not match" is a useful way to put it.

Comment: You might want to change your answer now that the question has been changed. I originally downvoted this, because it didn't seem to be addressing the actual question, but then saw you'd answered a previous version of the question. I reversed my vote, and added a note to the question to hopefully prevent other downvotes.

Comment: @JasonBassford Done. Thank you.